# Running electron-build on my create-react-app app comes up with an error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

Hi I am developing an Electron-react app using create-react-app boilerplate and electron-builder to package and deploy it.

However, on running electron-builder using yarn in the CL it shows this error.

```
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • loaded parent configuration  preset=react-cra
  • writing effective config  file=build\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=8.0.1 appOutDir=build\win-unpacked
  • default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set
  • building        target=nsis file=build\electron-react-typescript-app Setup 0.1.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  ⨯ write EPIPE     stackTrace=
                      Error: write EPIPE
                          at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:25)
                          at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:141:3)
                          at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:771:11)
                          at Socket._write (net.js:783:8)
                          at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
                          at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
                          at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
                          at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:594:10)
                          at Socket.end (net.js:575:31)
                          at C:\Users\andrew.choi\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\builder-util-npm-22.3.3-d8bf259145-2.zip\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:193:26
                          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
                          at spawnAndWrite (C:\Users\username\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\builder-util-npm-22.3.3-d8bf259145-2.zip\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:176:10)
                          at NsisTarget.executeMakensis (C:\Users\username\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\app-builder-lib-npm-22.3.3-dc71ab7fc0-2.zip\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:552:11)
                          at NsisTarget.computeScriptAndSignUninstaller (C:\Users\andrew.choi\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\app-builder-lib-npm-22.3.3-dc71ab7fc0-2.zip\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:340:5)
                          at NsisTarget.buildInstaller (C:\Users\username\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\app-builder-lib-npm-22.3.3-dc71ab7fc0-2.zip\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:278:103)
                          at NsisTarget.finishBuild (C:\Users\username\Documents\electron-react-app\.yarn\cache\app-builder-lib-npm-22.3.3-dc71ab7fc0-2.zip\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\targets\nsis\NsisTarget.ts:110:7)
command not found: electron-builder
```

Here is my package.json file.
I am using windows 10 if that matters.
And running "yarn dist" in the command prompt opened with administrators permissions

```
{
  "name": "electron-react-typescript-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/start.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "123456789",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "build"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "immer": "^5.3.2",
    "material-table": "^1.55.0",
    "mssql": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-desktop": "^0.3.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nodemon --exec \"\"electron .\"\"",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "start": "cross-env BROWSER=none nodemon npm run react-start",
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node ./server/server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "dev": "run-p server react-start",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3500",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "8.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-redux-devtools": "^0.3.4",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "express-pino-logger": "^4.0.0",
    "node-env-run": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pino-colada": "^1.5.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "description": "An Electron React App",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Icecubelegacy/Electron-react-app.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "electron"
  ],
  "author": "Andrew Choi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Icecubelegacy/Electron-react-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "postinstall": "electron-builder intall-app-deps"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved. 
I started a new project, specified the version of electron-builder as 22.3.5, ran yarn build and then ran yarn electron-pack. Then I went to my .dist folder and installed the setup exe and then was able to open the .exe application file successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`command not found: electron-builder`

This likely means that your `node_modules` folder doesn't have `electron-builder` under `node_modules/.bin`.

You can try running the command

```
yarn
```

which should get you `electron-builder` installed locally since it's listed under your `devDependencies` in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for the response~ I ran `yarn` and then tried to build again but got the same error. I looked in my node_modules folder and electron-builder is there.

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out on your own